# CGRectMake(currentobject.frame.origin.x, currentObject.fram.. quicker way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Quite often, I'll want to move an object along by 2 points, so I'll put:

```
CGRectMake(currentobject.frame.origin.x+2, currentObject.frame.origin.y, currentObject.frame.size.width, currentObject.frame.size.height);
```

Is there a quicker way, where either I can just change the 1 thing, or where I can quickly reference the current values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `CGRectOffset()`:

```
NSAssert(currentObject, @"%s: Must have |currentObject|.", __func__);
CGRect offsetFrame = CGRectOffset([currentObject frame], 2/*dx*/, 0/*dy*/);
[currentObject setFrame:offsetFrame];
```

Note the assertion: a method with a struct return value is one of the few cases where sending a message to `nil` can return junk rather than some equivalent to zero (0, 0.0, `nil`, `Nil`, &c.).

The equivalent of `CGRectOffset()` for growing or shrinking the frame (changing the size) is `CGRectInset()`.

An alternative to using `CGRectOffset()` when working with `UIView` is to just displace the view's center:

```
view.center.x += 2;
```

This updates the frame accordingly.

Comment: This should work most of the time. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-TPXREF116

Comment: @bddckr What is "this", and what portion of that multipage document are you referencing? What I had in mind with the assertion was ["Sending Messages to `nil`" in *The Objective-C Programming Language*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7). It looks like Apple's changes to the runtime since 10.4 have resulted in fewer classes of messages to `nil` that result in undefined behavior.

Comment: I was talking about the use of the ´CGRect´ helper functions Apple provides.

Comment: @bddckr Why only "most of the time"? When would `CGRectOffset()` not work?

Comment: The question reads "...where either I can just change 1 thing...", so I thought `CGRectOffset()` (plus all the other `CGRect*` functions) would be sufficient for most needs. Only problem is to wrap one's head around the `dx`, `dy` parameters for example, instead of just doing `x + 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
CGRect frame = currentObject.frame;
frame.origin.x += 2;
currentObject.frame = frame;
```

or

```
CGRect frame = (CGRect){ currentobject.frame.origin.x + 2, currentObject.frame.origin.y, currentObject.frame.size };
```